# Resizing a Rectangle inside a GridPane using percentage ColumnConstraints

Tags: resize, javafx-2, shapes

I have a `GridPane` with *n* columns & *n* rows, and a `Rectangle` in each cell (almost like a chess board). I'm trying to make the `Rectangle`s expand to take up all the space available in each cell, without expanding too far. Have tried a `ColumnConstraints` approach, but still don't know what to bind the `Rectangle`s' width to.

**Solution:** bind `Rectangle` width and height to a `NumberBinding`.

Example, makes a chess board:

```
GridPane board = new GridPane();
NumberBinding rectsAreaSize = Bindings.min(board.heightProperty(), board.widthProperty());

for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    {
        Rectangle rect;
        if(i % 2 == 0 ^ j % 2 == 0) // ^ is the XOR operator
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(15.0, 15.0, Color.WHITE);
        }
        else
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(15.0, 15.0, Color.BLACK);
        }
        rect.widthProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(size));
        rect.heightProperty().bind(rectsAreaSize.divide(size));

        board.add(rect, i, j);
        GridPane.setHalignment(rect, HPos.CENTER);
    }
}
```

References:

- [How to create dynamically Resizable shapes in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887485/how-to-create-dynamically-resizable-shapes-in-javafx)
- [Can a gridpane automatically resize it's objects to fit? Trying to set a max_width and max_height to a grid and have it resize content. JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9830206/can-a-gridpane-automatically-resize-its-objects-to-fit-trying-to-set-a-max-wid)